# Change texts in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to change text on our Magento homepage, but I can't do it. When I go to CMS -> pages -> homepage -> content, the thing I want to change isn't there. This is our website: http://bsw-bv.com/. Could anybody tell me how I can change the text in the blue boxes beneath the slider?

Comment: you need to find the how slider bind in homepage. Check layout section of page.

Comment: It's difficult to be certain of where content is pulled in from by simply looking at the output, but the content in the blue boxes looks like description data for the categories. If you log into the CMS and go:
CMS -> Catalog -> Manage Categories then expand the category list and look for each one, then change the "Description" data, you may need to flush the cache depending how your site is set up once you've saved the changes.

Comment: If you don't find anything on CMS HOME page then check the widget first. There could be some widget created to list those blocks which is beneath the slider. If you able to find widget, check the corresponding widget options and find the static block associated to it. I believe those contents are from static block. but make sure to take database backup and then do the rest of edit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try editing the text in the 'CMS -> Static Blocks' menu of the admin panel of your Magento store. You can try editing 'Homepage Image Carousel' entry from the list appears under this menu.

In case you are not able to edit the text in above menu then we can only say that the text you want to change is not a part of default Magento installation, but it is a part of your theme, we can only suggest you search for that particular text in your theme's PHTML files. Search for 'Professional Cleaning Solutions' in your case.